# Replace XML attribute with sed on Mac

Tags: regex, xml, macos, sed

I am trying to replace xml attribute with `sed` on Mac OS X but can't get it working.

I want to match `name="..."` and replace it with `name="Test"`.

I am using following sed, which is not working:

```
sed -i -E 's/name="\(.*?\)"/name="Test"/' file.xml
```

Can someone tell me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to catch the group, etc. This should suffice:

```
sed -E 's/name="[^"]*"/name="Test"/' file.xml
```

See it just looks for `name="` followed by any character not being from `"`.

#### Test

```
$ cat hi
<test name="hello buddy">aaa</test>
$ sed -E 's/name="[^"]*"/name="Test"/' hi
<test name="Test">aaa</test>
```